# Must not be called on the main application thread when using Firebase Tasks and Rx

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, rx-java2

I've a code that brings from DB the list of ids of user's favorite beers. Then I use Rx's flatMap to load beers info from database using              beerDataSource.loadBeer(it):

The execution starts at:

```
       loadFavoritesUseCase
        .execute(Unit)
        .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe { (it, _) ->
            info(it)
        }
```

then in UseCase:

```
    override fun execute(params: Unit): Observable<List<Beer>> {

    return favoriteDataSource
        .all()
        .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
        .map{
            info ("it: $it")
            it
        }
        .flatMap {
            beerDataSource.loadBeer(it)
        }
        .toList()
        .toObservable()
}
```

And loadBeer:

```
override fun loadBeer(id: String): Observable<Beer> {
    return Observable.defer {

        val taskSource = TaskCompletionSource<DataSnapshot>()


        val ref = database.reference.child(auth.currentUser?.uid).child("cache/beers").child(id)


        val listener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError?) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    taskSource.setException(databaseError.toException())

                }
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                taskSource.setResult(dataSnapshot)
            }
        }

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener)
        val task = taskSource.task
        Tasks.await(task)

        val beer = task.result.getValue(Beer::class.java)!!
        return@defer Observable.just(beer)
    }
}
```

When it trigger Tasks.await it throws an exception:

```
> 07-18 00:25:34.545 22810-23083/br.com.alexpfx.cervejas W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Must not be called on the main application thread
07-18 00:25:34.546 22810-23083/br.com.alexpfx.cervejas W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
07-18 00:25:34.547 22810-23083/br.com.alexpfx.cervejas W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the `Task.await(task)` that can't be run on the main UI thread.

I had a function called FirebaseOCR() with a `Task.await()` inside of it.

```
Thread(Runnable {
FirebaseOCR()
}).start()
```